# Visa rule to apply up to 3 months from the date of travel

Tags: visas, uk, applications

Does the the UK rule, to apply for visa up to 3 months before travel, start from the date of the online application or from the date of the appointment? And, should I pay my fees on the day of the appointment?

Comment: Your question is answered unambiguously with a simple Google search and the answer directly from [UK.GOV](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview) 

 _**How long it will take** The earliest you can apply is 3 months **before you travel**. Example You can apply from 16 March if you plan to travel on 15 June_.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered unambiguously with a simple Google search and the answer directly from [UK.GOV](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview)

> **How long it will take?**
>
> The earliest you can apply is 3 months **before you travel**. Example: You
>   can apply from 16 March if you plan to travel on 15 June.

Pay which fees? If you mean school fees, then there is no need in paying fees before the visa is issued. Many people lose nonrefundable fees that way.